# RxJava on Android: Undeliverable exception in blockingAwait on timeout

Tags: android, exception, rx-java

Can somebody, please explain why this code throws undeliverable exception and how to fix it:

```
val completable = Completable.fromAction { Thread.sleep(10000) }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
if (!completable.blockingAwait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    System.out.println("timeout triggered")
} else {
    System.out.println("all good")
}
```

When running this code it results in the following exception:

```
08-22 14:01:57.575 31345-31345/com.myapp I/System.out: timeout triggered

08-22 14:01:57.593 31345-31399/com.myapp [CRASH] : The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.InterruptedException , Abort
     Exception: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.InterruptedException`
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't subscribe to this completable so you cannot handle this exception. You have to setup some callback to handle such exceptions:

```kotlin
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { e ->
    // do something
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler%20%7B%20%20%7D)